# Android Studio how to use NetCipher

Tags: android, tor

I want to use this Lib in an Android Studio project. I am relatively new in Android Studio. Can someone explain me how to Import the [Netcipher Library](https://github.com/guardianproject/NetCipher) into my project?

I want to use this to connect a `WebView` to a Tor Hidden Service.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you must add the library to your gradle

```
compile 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher:2.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
```

Then add this code wherever you want, they recommend starting the app with this code.

```
                                    OrbotHelper.get(activity).statusTimeout(60000).addStatusCallback(new StatusCallback(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void onEnabled(Intent intent){
                                        try{
                                            WebkitProxy.setProxy("127.0.0.1", 8118);
                                        }catch(Exception e){
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onStarting(){
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onStopping(){
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onDisabled(){
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onStatusTimeout(){
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onNotYetInstalled(){
                                    }
                                }).init();
```

Then for your webview section - to connect orbot to your Webview. Name this file WebkitProxy.

```
package **.*****.**;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Proxy;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.ArrayMap;

import static freedom.theanarch.org.freedom.Main.*;

/**
* Created by brad on 8/28/17.
*/

public class WebkitProxy {

private final static int DEFAULT_SOCKS_PORT = 9050;

public static boolean setProxy(String host, int port)throws Exception{
    setSystemProperties(host, port);

    boolean worked = false;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13){
        setProxyUpToHC(host, port);
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
        worked = setWebkitProxyICS(host, port);
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 20){
        worked = setKitKatProxy(activity.getApplicationContext(), host, port);
        if(!worked){
            worked = setWebkitProxyICS(host, port);
        }
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        worked = setWebkitProxyLollipop(activity.getApplicationContext(), host, port);

    }

    return worked;
}

public static void resetProxy()throws Exception{
    resetSystemProperties();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13){
        resetProxyForGingerBread(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
        resetProxyForICS();
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 20){
        setKitKatProxy(activity.getApplicationContext(), "", 0);
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        setWebkitProxyLollipop(activity.getApplicationContext(), "", 0);
    }

}

private static void setSystemProperties(String host, int port){
    System.setProperty("proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("proxyPort", Integer.toString(port));

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(port));

    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", Integer.toString(port));


    System.setProperty("socks.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("socks.proxyPort", Integer.toString(DEFAULT_SOCKS_PORT));

    System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", Integer.toString(DEFAULT_SOCKS_PORT));
}

private static void resetSystemProperties(){
    System.setProperty("proxyHost", "");
    System.setProperty("proxyPort", "");

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "");

    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "");


    System.setProperty("socks.proxyHost", "");
    System.setProperty("socks.proxyPort", Integer.toString(DEFAULT_SOCKS_PORT));

    System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "");
    System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", Integer.toString(DEFAULT_SOCKS_PORT));
}

@SuppressWarnings("all")
private static boolean setProxyUpToHC(String host, int port){

    HttpHost proxyServer = new HttpHost(host, port);
    Class networkClass = null;
    Object network = null;
    try{
        networkClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.Network");
        if(networkClass == null){
            return false;
        }
        Method getInstanceMethod = networkClass.getMethod("getInstance", Context.class);
        network = getInstanceMethod.invoke(networkClass, new Object[]{activity.getApplicationContext()});
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return false;
    }
    if(network == null){
        return false;
    }
    Object requestQueue = null;
    try{
        Field requestQueueField = networkClass.getDeclaredField("mRequestQueue");
        requestQueue = getFieldValueSafely(requestQueueField, network);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return false;
    }
    if(requestQueue == null){
        return false;
    }
    Field proxyHostField = null;
    try{
        Class requestQueueClass = Class.forName("android.net.http.RequestQueue");
        proxyHostField = requestQueueClass.getDeclaredField("mProxyHost");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return false;
    }

    boolean temp = proxyHostField.isAccessible();
    try{
        proxyHostField.setAccessible(true);
        proxyHostField.set(requestQueue, proxyServer);
    }catch(Exception ex){
    }finally{
        proxyHostField.setAccessible(temp);
    }
    return true;
}


private static Object getFieldValueSafely(Field field, Object classInstance)throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    boolean oldAccessibleValue = field.isAccessible();
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object result = field.get(classInstance);
    field.setAccessible(oldAccessibleValue);
    return result;
}

private static boolean setWebkitProxyICS(String host, int port){
    try{
        Class webViewCoreClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewCore");

        Class proxyPropertiesClass = Class.forName("android.net.ProxyProperties");
        if(webViewCoreClass != null && proxyPropertiesClass != null){
            Method m = webViewCoreClass.getDeclaredMethod("sendStaticMessage", Integer.TYPE, Object.class);
            Constructor c = proxyPropertiesClass.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.TYPE, String.class);

            if(m != null && c != null){
                m.setAccessible(true);
                c.setAccessible(true);
                Object properties = c.newInstance(host, port, null);

                m.invoke(null, 193, properties);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
    return false;
}

@TargetApi(19)
private static boolean setKitKatProxy(Context appContext, String host, int port){
    if(host != null){
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(port));
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", Integer.toString(port));
    }

    try{
        Field loadedApkField = Main.class.getField("mLoadedApk");
        loadedApkField.setAccessible(true);
        Object loadedApk = loadedApkField.get(appContext);
        Class loadedApkCls = Class.forName("android.app.LoadedApk");
        Field receiversField = loadedApkCls.getDeclaredField("mReceivers");
        receiversField.setAccessible(true);
        ArrayMap receivers = (ArrayMap) receiversField.get(loadedApk);
        for(Object receiverMap : receivers.values()){
            for(Object rec : ((ArrayMap) receiverMap).keySet()){
                Class clazz = rec.getClass();
                if(clazz.getName().contains("ProxyChangeListener")){
                    Method onReceiveMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("onReceive", Context.class, Intent.class);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Proxy.PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION);

                    if(host != null){
                        final String CLASS_NAME = "android.net.ProxyProperties";
                        Class cls = Class.forName(CLASS_NAME);
                        Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.TYPE, String.class);
                        constructor.setAccessible(true);
                        Object proxyProperties = constructor.newInstance(host, port, null);
                        intent.putExtra("proxy", (Parcelable) proxyProperties);
                    }
                    onReceiveMethod.invoke(rec, appContext, intent);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

@TargetApi(21)
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static boolean setWebkitProxyLollipop(Context appContext, String host, int port){
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(port));
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", Integer.toString(port));
    try{
        Class applictionClass = Class.forName("android.app.Application");
        Field mLoadedApkField = applictionClass.getDeclaredField("mLoadedApk");
        mLoadedApkField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mloadedApk = mLoadedApkField.get(appContext);
        Class loadedApkClass = Class.forName("android.app.LoadedApk");
        Field mReceiversField = loadedApkClass.getDeclaredField("mReceivers");
        mReceiversField.setAccessible(true);
        ArrayMap receivers = (ArrayMap) mReceiversField.get(mloadedApk);
        for(Object receiverMap : receivers.values()){
            for(Object receiver : ((ArrayMap) receiverMap).keySet()){
                Class clazz = receiver.getClass();
                if(clazz.getName().contains("ProxyChangeListener")){
                    Method onReceiveMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("onReceive", Context.class, Intent.class);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Proxy.PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION);
                    onReceiveMethod.invoke(receiver, appContext, intent);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

private static void resetProxyForICS()throws Exception{
    try{
        Class webViewCoreClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewCore");
        Class proxyPropertiesClass = Class.forName("android.net.ProxyProperties");
        if(webViewCoreClass != null && proxyPropertiesClass != null){
            Method m = webViewCoreClass.getDeclaredMethod("sendStaticMessage", Integer.TYPE, Object.class);

            if(m != null){
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(null, 193, null);
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void resetProxyForGingerBread(Context ctx)throws Exception{
    Object requestQueueObject = getRequestQueue(ctx);
    if(requestQueueObject != null){
        setDeclaredField(requestQueueObject, "mProxyHost", null);
    }
}

public static Object getRequestQueue(Context ctx)throws Exception{
    Object ret = null;
    Class networkClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.Network");
    if(networkClass != null){
        Object networkObj = invokeMethod(networkClass, "getInstance", new Object[] { ctx }, Context.class);
        if(networkObj != null){
            ret = getDeclaredField(networkObj, "mRequestQueue");
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

private static Object getDeclaredField(Object obj, String name)throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Object out = f.get(obj);
    return out;
}

private static void setDeclaredField(Object obj, String name, Object value)throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(obj, value);
}

private static Object invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object[] params, Class... types)throws Exception{
    Object out = null;
    Class c = object instanceof Class ? (Class) object : object.getClass();
    if(types != null){
        Method method = c.getMethod(methodName, types);
        out = method.invoke(object, params);
    }else{
        Method method = c.getMethod(methodName);
        out = method.invoke(object);
    }
    return out;
}
}
```